# How can the Child window show in parent's non-client area

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

in word 2010, the ribbon bar is a child of the main window, but it shows in the top of main window (so, over the caption), how can they make child window shows in the parent's caption area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do if you point to the child's value.